# Why will 20.04 fossa not find my Star Lite laptop's integrated camera?

Tags: 20.04, laptop, camera

After installing 20.04 fossa, Cheese, Skype and Zoom cannot find my laptop's internal camera (they do locate a usb camera).  Before updating I was on 18.04 and all worked well.
I have experienced other odd differences (unrelated, I assume) on Ubuntu, but have found Cinnamon to do everything satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, during the downloading process, some old 18.04 files were not deleted or updated, so old and new settings had been in competition. In the midst of all this, BIOS settings were interfered with.

Solution: go to BIOS settings, revert to default settings and save.